# How to get all subdirectory names in a list with tcl?

Tags: list, directory, tcl

For the certain directory how I can get the child directory names in a list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **glob**. For example, for the current directory, the command to get all sub-directories is

```
glob -type d *
```

Or if you want a specific directory, use the **-directory** parameter:

```
glob -directory $mydir -type d *
```

Comment: You might want to add the -nocomplain flag to avoid error in case no sub directory found.

Comment: if I do something like this `set subdirs [ glob -drectory $mydir -type d * ] ; ` what is the type of variable subdirs is ? Is it a list? How to get the first element or an element containing a specific text from this list of sub directories.?? Need urgent help . Thanks!

Comment: glob -directory $path -type d *
does not work for me:
bad option "-type": must be -directory, -nocomplain, -tails, or --

Comment: (not work from integrated openOCD tcl)